# Get fields and values from an object by reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

With the class below, I try to get :

- field name
- value

I tried this piece of code :

```
Dictionary<string, string> listField = 
        membership.GetType()
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic)
            .ToDictionary(f => f.Name,
                          f => (string)f.GetValue(null));
```

but I have nothing in the dictionary.

Any idea ?

```
  [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="MyClass", Namespace="http://model.common.party.ent.gfdi.be")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
public partial class MyClass : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string firstName;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string lastName;

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private System.Nullable<long> fieldA;   

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private bool fieldB;    

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private int fieldC;     
}
```

Comment: I think you might be missing some binding flags, I'm no reflection guru but I remember having to specify `BindingFlags.Instance` to get instance level fields, (and vice versa for statics)

Comment: They are private fields. Why are you trying to serialize/deserialize them and why are you trying to get their values? Make them public instead.

Comment: Closer guys is not only find private but find private AND values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I think this will work:

```
Dictionary<string, string> listField =
membership.GetType()
         .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance) // <-- specify that you want instance fields
         .ToDictionary(f => f.Name,
                       f => (string)f.GetValue(membership)); // <-- IMPORTANT, 
                       // you need to specify an instance to get a value from a non-static field
```

The above code will only work for instance fields without modification

Comment: Works but ... I have some bool and DateTime fields in the class. I update the class in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const BindingFlags Flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
```

Comment: Why would you include `BindingFlags.Public` if there are only `private` fields?

Comment: you are most probaly right. just copied from my code where I solved similar issue